# Error in download.file; No such file or directory

Tags: r, csv

I'm an R programming newbie and was trying to download a file from:

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv

I used `download.file` and my code is:

```
url<-'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv'
doc<-download.file(url,destfile='./test/communities.csv')
```

I got an error:

> Error in download.file(url, destfile = "./test/communities.csv") : 
>     cannot open destfile './test/communities.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'

But when I check my working directory using `getwd()` it shows that it's there:

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/puneet.kumar/Desktop/R practice/R lesson/Data cleaning/test"
```

Can you please help me with this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There probably is no test folder in your test folder. So use `destfile='communities.csv'` or `destfile='../test/communities.csv'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`download.file(url = "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv", destfile = "communities.csv")`

That should do what you need. Since you're already in `test` you don't specify `./test` since that's looking for `.../test/test`.

Answer (score 0):

that means your file storage path wrong

```
define destfile="storefile"
```